# Can we communicate over USB Serial from KaiOS App?

Tags: serial-communication, kaios

I am quite new to KaiOS and was wondering if it is possible to build an app that sends / receives serial communications (for instance communicate with Arduino) over a physical cable connected to the phone.

I am currently doing it on Android using this library https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android, and would love to do it on KaiOS.

I looked at the permissions and see that there is nothing related (https://developer.kaiostech.com/core-developer-topics/permissions) but I did not find any info saying that it is possible (or not possible) to do it

If not possible, any idea of how to do Serial communication between a feature phone and an Arduino is welcomed !

Thanks for you help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. KaiOS phones do not support USB Host mode.

I've tried plugging USB mouse and keyboard in Nokia 2720 using USB OTG cable, the phone did not even provide +5V power to the USB port (my keyboard lights up LED if I plug it into USB charger)

Likewise, Bluetooth is limited to headphones, my Bluetooth mouse and Bluetooth gamepad did not work.